# Position one object based on another that's rotated

Tags: actionscript-3, math, geometry, polygon

I have a set of blocks which could be rotated at any angle. My task is to create an extra block to one side of the set, adjacent to the last block. I'm using Flex/AS3 and openscales. An illustration will be good to explain what I want to achieve. I apologise in advance for the crudeness of my pictures, I only have MS Paint to hand!

[image: Easy extra block]

[image: Wrong block]

[image: Corre2t block]

My current formula for the picture 2 is simply:

```
block5XPos += block4XPos - block3XPos;
block5YPos += block4YPos - block3YPos;
```

** Edit **

I cannot work with Display Objects in the usual way i.e. rotate, addChild. I'm restricted to utilising x and y values and having to re-calculate these values.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution allows, you could put all your blocks in a parent movieclip, rotate that movieclip. And then just modify the x parameter when you add new blocks to the parent movieclip. This would translate the block along the "local" x axis of the rotated parent.

Pseudocode:

```
var parent:MovieClip = new MovieClip()
parent.rotation = 45
addChild(parent)

var block1 = new BlockClip()
block1.x = 10
parent.addChild(block1)


var block2 = new BlockClip()
block2.x = 20
parent.addChild(block2)
```

Comment: no need for `MovieClip` here (which introduces more problems than it solves), instead use a simple `Sprite` as the container.

Comment: yes, a movieclip is overkill, but it wouldnt introduce any problems. Care to share those "more problems than it solves"?

Comment: Being overkill **is** a problem. If there's no need for a time line, then don't use one. You aren't adding some videos that you do not intend to display to the container either. Using the appropriate classes/types makes the code more self documenting. If I see `MovieClip`, I'd expect some time line interaction. On top of all that, it's `dynamic`, which means `new MovieClip().adChild(o);` fails silently at runtime, whereas `new Sprite().adChild(o);` causes a **compile time** error. Good luck finding that typo in a large project. `Sprite` should be the first choice.

Comment: upvote for good general points. But as you mention no actual problems are introduced here, only speculation and preference. Also adChild() would throw an error at runtime

Comment: The actual problem is the use of `MovieClip`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer zedd, the issue is I'm restricted to x and y values and having to re-calculate these.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I leveraged Math.cos and Math.sin to calculate the position of the new block based on the angle and distance from the last block.

```
    private function calculateNewSlotPosition(slot:SlotDO):void {
        var blockToRadians:Number = blockDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
        var cos:Number = Math.cos(blockToRadians);
        var sin:Number = Math.sin(blockToRadians);

        for(var k:uint = 0; k < block.polygon.length; k++) {
            block.polygon[k].x += ((block.width + workBlock.gap) * cos);
            block.polygon[k].y -= ((block.width + workBlock.gap) * sin);
        }
    }
```